# how to send parameter along with url in angular and not from body

Tags: angular

I have a post method i need to post parameter along with the address,i dont wana send from body,i want to send in my url

```
 qid="msq";
 this.http.post("http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/qid",{}).subscribe(s=>

  console.log(s);
});
```

Comment: what do you mean? how should I put "qid" as a parameter? can I pass data as query parameters to a post Api instead of using body? or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can send your object with params like below. i consider mydata to be object having the data.

```
this.http.post("http://localhost:44301/consentinitiation/qid",undefined, {params: mydata}).subscribe(s=>

  console.log(s);
});
```